# In C# is there no way to make a class define a field using an Interface or abstract class?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

I would like to force a set of classes to define three fields (of type string).
In an abstract class, I get that fields cannot be abstract and in an interface, I get an error saying that an interface cannot contain a field.
Is there no way to do this or am I not understanding this correctly? I'd rather not use methods because for some weird reason, the parentheses annoy me.

Comment: Must you use fields? Can you use properties instead?

Comment: What would an `abstract` field _mean_?

Comment: Why not just make the fields non-abstract in an abstract base class?

Comment: Stab in the dark, but, I think he means declare fields in the base class, which must then be initialized in derived/implementing classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone else says, use properties instead of fields, but you can do something like I interpreted in the comments as follows for read-only members:

```
abstract public class Base
{
    abstract public string Foo { get; }
    abstract public string Bar { get; }
    abstract public string Baz { get; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override string Foo { get { return "foo"; } }
    public override string Bar { get { return "bar"; } }
    public override string Baz { get { return "baz"; } }
}
```

If you want the fields to be modifiable later, you'll have to either use [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) or declare concrete backing fields and getter/setter pairs for each property.

Answer (score 6):

You can use properties for that:

```
interface MyInterface {
  string Prop1 { get; set; }
  string Prop2 { get; set; }
  string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Interface or abstract members force derived classes to provide code.
Fields don't have code.

You should use a property, which can be used like a field, but has code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Properties instead of fields:

```
// works similarly for Interfaces too
abstract class MyAbstractClass { public virtual string MyProperty1 { get; set; } }

class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass {  }
```

Then you can access MyProperty1 from any instance derived from MyAbstractClass:

MyAbstractClass obj1 = new MyConcreteClass;
obj1.MyProperty1 = "abcd";

Comment: You beat me to it with an example.  @Matt: this is a major difference between Java and C#.  What he shows is an automatically implemented property.  You can add a body to either the get, or the set in the abstract class or its sub classes.  Also note: you can add any visibility restrictions you like on: a) the property itself. b) the get, and c) the set.  (so `public` and `private` and `internal`, etc. etc.)